# Find Control in Dynamic Created Table Row C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, tablerow

I've created a table row dynamically using one function as shown here.

```
Table The_Table = Invoice_Table;
TableRow new_Item_Row = new TableRow();
The_Table.Rows.Add(new_Item_Row);

TableCell new_type = new TableCell();
TableCell new_item = new TableCell();
TableCell new_amount = new TableCell();

DropDownList type_List = new DropDownList();
type_List.ID = "type_List";
   ListItem Cash = new ListItem();
   Cash.Value="Cash";
   Cash.Text="Cash/Cheque";
   ListItem IVoi = new ListItem();
   IVoi.Value="IVoi";
   IVoi.Text="Invoice";
   type_List.Items.Add(Cash);
   type_List.Items.Add(IVoi);

TextBox item_Text = new TextBox();
item_Text.ID = "item_Text";

TextBox amount_Text = new TextBox();
amount_Text.ID = "amount_Text";

new_type.Controls.Add(type_List);
new_item.Controls.Add(item_Text);
new_amount.Controls.Add(amount_Text);

new_Item_Row.Cells.Add(new_type);
new_Item_Row.Cells.Add(new_item);
new_Item_Row.Cells.Add(new_amount);
```

I then try to access this control later using the following in a different function

```
 DropDownList type_L = Invoice_Table.FindControl("type_List") as DropDownList;
 TextBox amount_p = Invoice_Table.FindControl("amount_Text") as TextBox;
 TextBox Item_T = Invoice_Table.FindControl("item_Text") as TextBox;
```

but it is returning 
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I assume it is because it can't find the control? But I'm not sure how to fix it.

Sorry for the messiness of adding new cells... I'm new to this and I am not aware of any better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that FindControl is not recursive. You have to call it on the TableCell instance and not the Table itself.

```
TextBox amount_p = new_amount.FindControl("amount_Text") as TextBox;
```